# Click image and show up text under it

Tags: html, css

I am working on a responsive website that has a section with three images and when you click, under them there is a text.
In order to make a text show up when clicking on 3 images is that only 1 text is shown up and not 3 of each one image. I hope was cleared.

```
<script>function showStuff() {
                let hidden = document.getElementById('hidden');
                if (hidden.style.display == "none") {
                  hidden.style.display = "block"
                } else {
                  hidden.style.display = "none"
                }
              }
             </script> 

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Martial Arts </h3>
                <div class="feature">                   
                        <div class="portfolio">
                            <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
                                <img src="img/meditation1.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>                  
                </div>
                <div id="hidden"style="display: none">
                    <p class="lead">20 years plus veteran of martial arts, I have continued to train in different forms and styles from Karate to Kung Fu, to be able to set up Sanctuary Martial Arts, giving you an all round self defence, self preservation and self esteem system that is not a sports based martial art, but an easy and adaptable form.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Meditation</h3>
                <div class="feature">                   
                        <div class="portfolio">
                            <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
                                <img src="img/meditation2.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>                  
                </div>
                <div id="hidden"style="display: none">
                <p class="lead">Self care and self esteem comes from within.
                Following our guided meditation in standing, walking, seated and of course movement, you will find your inner calm and confidence.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3>Wellbeing</h3>
                <div class="feature">                   
                        <div class="portfolio">
                            <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
                                <img src="img/meditation3.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>                  
                </div>
                <div id="hidden"style="display: none">
                <p class="lead">Wellbeing comes in many forms, from what you eat, to how you keep the body and mind healthy.
                With guidance you can become more aware and more confident in the protection of your physical and emotional wellbeing.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**UPDATED:** According to the answer of this topic I decided to create a function.js file with the already code but with the changes that made at  numbers of name of the functions and classes.

```
function showStuff() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff2() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden2');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff3() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden3');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff4() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden4');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff5() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden5');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff6() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden6');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff7() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden7');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff8() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden8');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
  function showStuff9() {
    let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden9');
    for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
  }
```

Comment: An `id` can only occur once in a webpage. For multiple elements you have to use `class`.

Comment: an example about this?

Comment: You can read more about class and id selectors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using id for multiple div so everytime it is picking first div with id hidden.
If you want all the text to be shown on any click then the code will be

```
<script>
   function showStuff() {
       let hidden = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
       for(let i = 0 ; i < hidden.length; i++){
           if (hidden[i].style.display == "none") {
               hidden[i].style.display = "block"
           } else {
               hidden[i].style.display = "none"
           }
       }
   }
</script> 
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Martial Arts </h3>
   <div class="feature">
      <div class="portfolio">
         <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
         <img src="img/meditation1.png">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden"style="display: none">
      <p class="lead">20 years plus veteran of martial arts, I have continued to train in different forms and styles from Karate to Kung Fu, to be able to set up Sanctuary Martial Arts, giving you an all round self defence, self preservation and self esteem system that is not a sports based martial art, but an easy and adaptable form.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Meditation</h3>
   <div class="feature">
      <div class="portfolio">
         <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
         <img src="img/meditation2.png">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden"style="display: none">
      <p class="lead">Self care and self esteem comes from within.
         Following our guided meditation in standing, walking, seated and of course movement, you will find your inner calm and confidence.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Wellbeing</h3>
   <div class="feature">
      <div class="portfolio">
         <a href="#meditation" onClick="showStuff()" target="_self">
         <img src="img/meditation3.png">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="hidden"style="display: none">
      <p class="lead">Wellbeing comes in many forms, from what you eat, to how you keep the body and mind healthy.
         With guidance you can become more aware and more confident in the protection of your physical and emotional wellbeing.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This shows all hidden items at once instead of just the one hidden element clicked on.

Comment: @Junky yes I have given the code to show all at once because as per question the text was coming of only first div and not for others

Comment: @Kunika then for each of the text have to be different function, right?

Comment: @RubenOchoa yes for that case you will need to make the different function in which you will have to look at the sibling hidden of current feature class and make the changes accordingly